# c# dataGridView for loop to add data

Tags: c#, datagridview

Use a for loop to generate numbers, 1-100, and add each number to the dataGridView

After I tried with my code, I only showed one line, which is the last 100.

```
public void aaa(int i) {
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    dt.Columns.Add("host");

    DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
    for (int a = 1; a <= i; a++)
    {
        dr[a] = i;
    }
    dt.Rows.Add(dr);

    this.dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    for (int i = 1; i <= 254; i++)
    {
        aaa(i);
    }       
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I thought of the available solutions myself.

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable(); 
dt.Columns.Add("number"); 
int i = 10; 
int a = 0; 
while (a<=i) 
{ 
    DataRow dr = dt.NewRow(); 
    a++; 
    dr[0] = a; 
    dt.Rows.Add(dr);
 } 
this.dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
```

Answer (score 3):

your `btn_click` function. Every loop will initialize or create a new object inside the `aaa(i)` function

Every time `aaa(i)` is called in the for loop `DataTable dt = new DataTable()` will be called

```
public void aaa(int i)
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable(); ///this will initialize every time, a new data table will be created every loop
    dt.Columns.Add("host");

    DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
    for (int a = 1; a <= i; a++)
    {
        dr[a] = i;
    }
        dt.Rows.Add(dr);

    this.dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
}
```

}

Might i suggest you pass the `254` int in your `aaa(i)` function and do the loop inside like

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   aaa(254);
}


public void aaa(int i) //value of i = 254
{
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
        for (var s = 0; s <= i; s++ ) {
            for (int a = 1; a <= i; a++)
            {
                dr[a] = i;
            }
                dt.Rows.Add(dr);

            this.dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
        }
    }
}
```

or if the reason for the loop in the button is just for the number limit in the loop inside void `aaa` then you can simplify it as

```
public void aaa(int i) //value of i = 254
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
    for (int a = 1; a <= i; a++)
    {
        dr[a] = i;
    }
    dt.Rows.Add(dr);

    this.dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I always do this like that

```
ListCollectionView collectionView;
collectionView = new ListCollectionView(*your list of items*);

datagridView1.ItemSource = collectionView;
```

Implementing like this give you in future open way for sorting, filtering etc. [Here is link to ms documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.data.listcollectionview?view=netframework-4.8). where you will find more information about `listCollectionView`.